# auto&& variable's are not rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, forwarding-reference

Why auto&& is not rvalue reference?

```
Widget&& var1 = Widget(); // rvalue reference
auto&& var2 = var1; //var2 not rvalue reference
```

below are rvalue reference example

```
void f(Widget&& param); // rvalue reference
Widget&& var1 = Widget(); // rvalue reference
```

Why var2 is not rvalue reference but f and var2 are rvalue references?

Comment: I'd recommend reading [this article](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) on forwarding references (previously known as universal references).

Comment: add `auto&& var3 = 10` as an rvalue reference

Comment: Because named rvalue references are lvalues.

Comment: "lvalue reference" and "rvalue reference" refer to how a reference is bound. After binding it's just a reference, there is no longer any distinction other than the result of `decltype`.  Please update your question to show how you are determining "not rvalue reference"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the type of the initializer has been determined, the compiler determines the type that will replace the keyword `auto` using the rules for template argument deduction from a function call (see template argument deduction#Other contexts for details). The keyword `auto` may be accompanied by modifiers, such as `const` or `&`, which will participate in the type deduction.

For example, given

```
const auto& i = expr;
```

The type of `i` is exactly the type of the argument `u` in an imaginary

```
template template<class U> 
void f(const U& u)
```

If the function call `f(expr)` was compiled.

In general , it can be think as below .

```
 template template<class U> 
    void f(paramtype u)
```

Therefore, `auto&&` may be deduced either as an lvalue reference or rvalue reference according to the initializer.

In your case , imaginary template would look like

```
 template template<class U> 
        void f(U&& var2){}
f(var1)
```

Here ,`var1` is named rvalue which is being treated as lvalue, so `var2` will be deduced as lvalue .

Consider the following examples:

```
auto&& var2 = widget() ; //var2 is rvalue reference here .
int x=10;
const int cx=10;
auto&& uref1 = x; // x is int and lvalue, so uref1's type is int&
auto&& uref2 = cx; // cx is const int and lvalue,  so uref2's type is const int&
auto&& uref3 = 27; // 27 is int and rvalue,  so uref3's type is int&&
```

Answer (score 5):

`auto&&` is a declaration's equivalent of forwarding references (with identical deduction rules). As such, it will be deduced to an lvalue reference when the initializer is an lvalue. However, `var` is an lvalue (as it is the name of a variable), hence `var2` is an lvalue reference.