# Difference between lvalue reference and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have been studying addition of rvalue reference in C++11. It wasn't straightforward but I feel like I am finally starting to get a grasp of it. However there is one particular instance where I am confused. Specifically I don't get what is the meaning of 'b' in this example:

```
int a = 27;
int&& b = 27;
```

EDIT: I know that int a = 27 is an lvalue not lvalue reference.

Also what I looking for is not what int&& b = 27 **is** but what is it **meaning** intuitively. I am confused because I thought that rvalues where not addressable, but here we have a reference to rvalue which means we can adress it. So how come it is still an rvalue?

Comment: possible dupplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899538/auto-variables-are-not-rvalue-reference

Comment: @elvis.dukaj That's not the correct duplicate

Comment: I know that int a= 27 is not an lvalue reference. It's an lvalue. I was just showing this as they seem to mean the same thing here ( although I know they don't). Also, I am sure there is million of questions about lvalue and rvalue but I specifically want to know what 'int&& = 27' mean.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you assign a literal constant to an rvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085796/what-happens-when-you-assign-a-literal-constant-to-an-rvalue-reference)

Answer (score 6):

`int a = 27;` is a *statement*, and is neither an lvalue nor an rvalue. It defines the *name* `a`, which can be used as an lvalue *expression*, of type `int`.

`int&& b = 27;` is also a *statement* and the name `b` is used as an lvalue *expression* of type `int&&`, and permits a conversion to an xvalue expression of type `int`

Comment: I see. So int&& can be explicitly converted to int?

Comment: @dawid You can initialise an `int` from an `int&&` just like from an `int` or an `int&`, yes. In the specific case of `int` there is no difference, but initialising a `std::vector<int>` from a `std::vector<int>&&` will do something different than from a `std::vector<int>&`

Answer (score 5):

> but here we have a reference to rvalue which means we can adress it. So how come it is still an rvalue?

Given `int&& b = 27;`, a [temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) `int` is constructed from `27` and then `b` binds to the temporary. (And the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of `b`.) After that if you get the address like `&b` you'll get the address of the temporary.

BTW `b` is an lvalue itself.

> Temporary objects are created `when a prvalue is materialized so that it can be used as a glvalue, which occurs (since C++17)` in the following situations:
>
> - binding a reference to a prvalue

BTW: It's not special for rvalue reference; same thing happens for `const int& b = 27;`.

Answer (score -1):

B is rvalue reference and you can assign only rvalue to it.

Comment: I know that it is an rvalue reference.

Comment: You need to be more specific in your question

Comment: Ian, this is EXACLTY what I wanted to know. So it is an lvalue which means that a and b are equal in type?